# $.browser.version for Safari 6?

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a little issue for Safary < 6. I'm not a Mac user, and I have no Mac in my office. And the Safari 6 is not available for Windows. What I need is to know the

```
$.browser.version
```

for the Safari 6 web browser. Mac developers, could you tell me that info? Thanks.

Comment: FYI, from the jQuery docs: `The $.browser property is deprecated in jQuery 1.3`

Comment: I know. I need the version value only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've been warned that browser sniffing is not usually the preferred method. That said, `$.browser` parses the user agent string. A glance at user agent strings from www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/ reveals Safari 6 as:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25`

The part after `AppleWebKit` is where jQuery picks up the rendering engine version.  So, in this case, it's `536.26`. You can try this yourself by spoofing your user agent string. In Firefox, User Agent Switcher is an addon that does this. Go to http://whatsmyua.com to see what jQuery sees.